# centering within a form within a section

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Im using bootstrap 4 and have this form in a section that Im having issues with centering the button and making it the length of the two columns so that its even with input-boxes outer border. currently if i just have button at 100% width it appears centered but is longer than the inputs boxes so it looks off. Do I have it structured correctly? I used a form off there examples and am not sure if this is correct or if there is a better way.

here is my codepen:https://codepen.io/robot_head/full/qKQwqe/

html for that section:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center" id="contact">
    <h3>CONTACT US</h3><br>
    <div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2">

        <form role="form">
        <br style="clear:both">
<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="control" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
                    </div>
</div>

    <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">SEND</button>
        </form>

</div>
</div>
      </div>
```

css:

```
#contact{
  background-color: #febb2e;
  height: 500px;
  color: #000;
}
.form-area
{
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 10px 40px 60px;
    margin: 10px 0px 60px;
    border: 1px solid GREY;
    }
.control{
  display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
button#submit {
    background-color: #8d1f2d;
    border-color: #8d1f2d;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can fix them in  many ways, the reason for the issue is that the col-sm-6 class has a padding 15px on both sides, and your button does not have any padding. As a quick fix either you can wrap your button in a div with class col-sm-12 or just add a padding of 15px on left and right of the button.

Comment: ok cool but say i reduced the width to  60% how would i keep it centered still, it seems to stick to the side when i do that?

Comment: it is because you have a class called pull-right on the button, which is keeping button float to right side, remove that class, you should be good